# A-Frame Networked Components - Help Needed

Tags: javascript, html, aframe, oculusquest, aframe-networked

I am fairly new to A-frame and was working on a side project using the networked-aframe.
I was able to create multiple users and to move around the scene and watch all the users walk around the scene.

However, when I tried to create an entity and make it grabbable, movable and scalable using super-hands and physics https://github.com/c-frame/aframe-super-hands-component (i am using Oculus Quest 2), the modifications are replicated on one device, OR I create multiple duplicate entities (one for each client connected) and the one local to the oculus quest 2 will have its properties changed.

Is there a way to create a single shared entity between all clients where all the clients are able to change its entities? Am i missing something?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.